# Unable to Raise SystemExit with following code

Tags: python

Just started with Python, learning about while loops, wondering why this won't exit

Have gotten the responses to work, however when trying to exit out of the program it just continues looping as normal.

```
# Yes or No?
import random

# LIST OF RESPONSES

r = [
'Yes',
'No',
'Maybe']

def yn(input):
    while True:
        # Y/N Question
        input('Ask a yes or No question \n').lower()
        answer = random.choice(r)
        if input != 'exit':
            print(answer)
        else:
            print('Thank you')
            raise SystemExit



print(yn(input))
```

Comment: `input` is a function, not the input you read. You threw that input in the trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to assign the result of `input` to a variable, then check that.

```
res = input('Ask a yes or No question \n').lower()
if res != 'exit':
    print(answer)
else:
    raise SystemExit
```